# iOS App Crashed for a few Device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

The app is working well for all the devices, but in a particular device, it crashes just after launch. I didn't get any crash log through BugFender for it. But, App Store crashes give a stack trace. This stack trace is not indicating the cause of the crash.

[image]

Device Specifications: iPhone 6, iOS 10.2.1
App Specifications: App uses push notification, background fetching, contacts, mobile data, calendar, realm, Swift 2.3.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "few devices" ? there must be some specific model and os version on which app is crashing

Comment: It is crashing on a iPhone 6, iOS 10.2.1 .  But, it works well with the same configuration on other device.

Comment: Make sure you have provided appropriate keys for requesting Push Notification & Contacts Access.

Comment: @YahyaIbrahim Thanks, I checked it. It was perfect.  Push Notification & Contacts access is working well.  Actually, I don't understand why it happened for a particular device.

Comment: @MilanKamilya this happened with me as well.. The crash occurred  on iPad Pro (when the app was in review). It never crashed in simulator or on devices. Luckily the same app was approved (obviously without crash) when resubmitting after 3-4 days.

Comment: @YahyaIbrahim Great. This app has been approved by App Store a long ago.

Comment: I think you should implement crashlytics to get a better idea.

Comment: The Bugfender and Crashlytics do the same job. But, the crash happens before they initialize.

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching data from Contacts and Calenders right ? There might be chances that you have some wrong records in contacts and application get crashed.

We had same issue in one of our apps in which we used to fetch contacts from Contacts application. We had one wrong records. So, once we deleted it then issue get solved. If you're syncing data for Contacts and Calenders then check with other devices with same data.

Comment: You have a good point. I did as you said, but didn't resolve the problem. In this case, no contacts has been fetched because the app didn't finishes its launching. So, the problem is not with Contacts.